# Prove $\lvert X \setminus Y \rvert = \mathfrak{c}$ if $\lvert X \rvert = \mathfrak{c} $ and $\lvert Y \rvert = \aleph_0$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

As part of a solution to a question I'm doing right now, I need to prove the theorem stated in the title. While it seems quite obvious, I don't know how to actually prove it. 
Any help will be very appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've tried finding an invertible function from $X \setminus Y$ to $X$, without great success.

Comment: What have you tried?Please include your attempt in the question. More context would be helpful too.

Comment: First try getting a bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{N}$. Hint: Use a bijection between $[0,1)$ and $(0,1)$ to construct the bijection between \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{N}$. Then you can use this bijection to complete the proof.

Comment: From [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.**

Answer (score 2):

You can use these two observations:

- Under the given assumptions, you have $|X\setminus Y|\ge \aleph_0$.
- If $|A|\ge\aleph_0$, then $|A|+\aleph_0=|A|$.

**We have $|X\setminus Y|\ge \aleph_0$.** If $|X\setminus Y|<\aleph_0$ we would get that $|X|=|Y|+|X\setminus Y|\le \aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$, a contradiction. So we have the opposite inequality - $|X\setminus Y|\ge\aleph_0$.

Notice that here we're using that cardinalities of any two sets are comparable - which is basically axiom of choice. (Of course, if you are working with some specific $X$ and $Y$, it is possible that you can immediately see that $|X\setminus Y|\ge\aleph_0$.)

You can also have a look at this post: [Does $k+\aleph_0=\mathfrak{c}$ imply $k=\mathfrak{c}$ without the Axiom of Choice?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30282) (Especially if you want an argument avoiding AC.) Several [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/30282) are close to yours. (Some of them for some specific sets $X$ and $Y$ rather than in full generality.)

**$|A|+\aleph_0=|A|$ whenever $|A|\ge\aleph_0$.** This is basically the "Hilbert hotel" argument. The inequality $|A|\ge\aleph_0$ means that we have a "copy" of $\mathbb N$ inside $A$. For this copy we can find a bijection with "two copies" of the same set. (This is the same proof as $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$.)